# Submiting Form using Jquery and Ajax without action attribute

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

This is my form in while loop

```
<?php 
                    $sql=mysqli_query($dbconfig,"SELECT * FROM faq ORDER BY faqID DESC");
                    while($faqList=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                    ?>
            <form id="myForm" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" id="xAction" name="xAction" value="answerQ">
            <input type="hidden" id="faqID" name="faqID" value="<?php echo $faqList['faqID']; ?>">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="answer" name="answer" placeholder="Answer to this question" ></textarea>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Answer" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rect"></form>
            <?php } ?>
```

This is my Ajax Code

```
 <script>
    $("#submit").click(function() {
                var faqID= $("#faqID").val();
                var answer= $("#answer").val();
                var xAction= $("#xAction").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "insertData.php",
                    data: 'faqID=' + faqID+ '&answer=' + answer+' & xAction=' + xAction,
                    success: function(result) {
                       alert(result);
                    }
                });


            });
    </script>
```

and this is my inserData.php file

```
if($_REQUEST['xAction'] == 'answerQ'){
    $faqID = ($_REQUEST['faqID']);
    $answer = ($_REQUEST['answer']);
    $sql = "UPDATE faq SET answer='".$answer."' WHERE faqID = '".$faqID."'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if($res){
        header('location:faqList.php?faqID='.$faqID.''); exit;
        }
}
```

SO i want to use ajax for inserting data into database but its not working at all but when i use action attribute in form then it work but then i could do that even without ajax if i had to so i want to carry out data inserting using ajax only.

Comment: ` var xAction= $("#xAction").val();` where did you have define this?

Comment: yes i tried using that also but it did not work i have edited my form and included xAction but still did not work

Comment: check your console.log()

Comment: anchor tag work fine with this ajax code but form is not working without action

Comment: replace `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: nope the button doesnt work if i use button for submit

Comment: You HAVE to switch submit to button, otherwise it submits to a nonexistent action and the page reloads and you lose your data. Call your ajax on button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too many errors in script.

First of all, a document can't have multiple id attribute with same name if you are creating form in while loop then id should be unique or you can use class.

In the js you should fetch data from particular form which is being submitted.

```
<script>
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();        //prevent form to submit
            var formData= $(this).closest('form').serialize();        //fetch form data
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insertData.php",
                data: formData,
                success: function(result) {
                   alert(result);
                }
            });


        });
</script>
```

in php script, you can't use header for redirect user when you are submitting data with ajax, you can use

```
 success: function(result) {
               alert(result);
               window.location = "page.php";
            }
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: what about form im confuse over their

Comment: i did not understand which form has called by this ajax as no form id is called in the ajax code or class

Comment: I used this  var formData= $(this).closest('form').serialize(); 
By this, that form will be selected to fetch data from, in which submit button is pressed, mean $(this) will be element which is pressed (current element) and closest() will find nearest parent from( because submit button is child of form) and most nearest form will fetched.

Comment: You should use particular id or class you are creating form in loop so what about if script create 25 forms. Would you code for every form? and how would you know that how much forms will be created.? so use a dynamic solution like i shared.

Comment: Yes yes i got that  but where does id's of the form play their role in the ajax

Comment: Why you need id of form,when we are traversing and fetching whole data from selected form? Id is worse part if you are creating a form with loop.

Comment: Nope i dont need id but what is happening with mi is at a time two form are working when submit is click though the search form is not close to the ajax query